# SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() not working on iOS 14

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit, ios14

as I say in the title, the

```
[SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
```

is not working anymore in iOS 14.
Does anyone know the alternative?

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_? You need to specify what problem you are encountering. Does the method not do anything?

Comment: The method does not do anything because requestReview has been deprecated, but 
I don't know what it has been replaced with

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The iOS14+ version of the `requestReview` function is `requestReviewInScene:`. See its [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/3566727-requestreview).

If you need to support both the old and new version of the function, you can use `if (@available(iOS ...)` checks (code written by @Maray97):

```
if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) { 
    [SKStoreReviewController requestReviewInScene:self.view.window.windowScene]; 
} else if (@available(iOS 10.3, *)) { 
    [SKStoreReviewController requestReview]; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, solved!
if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
                [SKStoreReviewController requestReviewInScene:self.view.window.windowScene];
            } else if (@available(iOS 10.3, *)) {
                [SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
            }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. It works for me with cordova plugin.

```
if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
    [SKStoreReviewController requestReviewInScene:self.viewController.view.window.windowScene];
} else if (@available(iOS 10.3, *)){
    [SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
}
```